# Decrease size of request when using ajax - codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In soundcloud.com , when i type 'a' in search box - view-source - and client receive: `XHR - method GET - size 714B`.

Open this link, i have JSON text: `{"collection:......"}`(*).

Codeigniter, when I using ajax POST, i also transmit like JSON text (*).
When view-source, client receive: `XHR size ~ 1,5KB`. [> 714B same JSON text]

I think, if used codeigniter, session or cookie will be received. I try off cookie or session. But Nothing changes!

How to reduce size of request ajax post?
Hope someone can help me explain.

Thanks!

Jquery:

```
var m = {JSON text(*)}
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url: test,
     data: {m:m},
     dataType : 'JSON',
     success: function(data) {
          //only receive data
          log(data);},
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function test(){   
//{Json text (*) - same Json from soundcloud.com}
$result = $this->input->post('m',TRUE)
print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using?

Comment: @Rahi - I try to test code - please, if you have ever experienced?

Comment: Try to edit you answer with full jQuery code. May be a along with JSON example.